# How should I draw a biased axes numbers in pstricks

Tags: pstricks

Here is the question. Pstricks normally draws an axes with given Dy/Dx and dy/dx and the generated plot has the same length sections all over divided by equally distant ticks. What if we wanted to have biased start tick position different from the specified Dy?
Here is an example plot with a biased y-axes tick start position:

[image: biased y-axes start tick]

Here is the code I need to get a hand into:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
\pscurve[showpoints=false]{}(0.31,0.5)(0.8,1.45)(1.31,2.21)(1.9,2.86)%
(2.58,3.41)(3.45,3.89)(4.29,3.89)(4.38, 3.41)%
(4.19, 2.86)(3.89,2.21)(3.61,1.45)(3.37,0.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame, showorigin=false, ylogBase=10, arrowscale=1.5,%
ticksize = -0.08, Ox=150, xunit=0.78,Dx=50,dx=1,%
Oy = 1, yunit=0.33, Dy=1, dy=5](0,0)(8,15)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you come up with an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame, showorigin=false, ylogBase=10, arrowscale=1.5,%
ticksize = -0.08, Ox=150, xunit=0.78,Dx=50,dx=1,
Oy=1,yunit=0.33,Dy=1,dy=5](0,0)(8,15)
\pscurve(0.31,0.5)(0.8,1.45)(1.31,2.21)(1.9,2.86)%
  (2.58,3.41)(3.45,3.89)(4.29,3.89)(4.38, 3.41)%
  (4.19, 2.86)(3.89,2.21)(3.61,1.45)(3.37,0.5)
\rput(1,0){%
  \pscurve[linecolor=red](0.31,0.5)(0.8,1.45)(1.31,2.21)(1.9,2.86)%
    (2.58,3.41)(3.45,3.89)(4.29,3.89)(4.38, 3.41)%
    (4.19, 2.86)(3.89,2.21)(3.61,1.45)(3.37,0.5)}
\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(1,0.25)(1,4.75)
\rput*(1,1){\small\red123}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid not.
Could you recognize the distance between origin and position of "0.0" point on y axes? It is almost half the distant between "0.2" and "0.4" on the y axes, suggesting that point "0.0" has a biased placement on y axes. I need to learn the way to adjust this bias.
Here is the [image](http://snag.gy/XA3jD.jpg).